# mapping a yaml file in python

Tags: python, yaml, data-science

This is a YAML file. It contains a list of mappings from ticker to feature category.

Following is the mapping of BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W:

```
index: [ BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: books,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: trends,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: trades,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: relations,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: books,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: trends,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: trades,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: negrelations,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: books,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: trends,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: trades,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: relations,BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: options_banknifty_weekly,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_10_W: books,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_10_W: trends,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_10_W: trades,BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_10_W: negrelations,BANKNIFTY_F_0: books,BANKNIFTY_F_0: trends,BANKNIFTY_F_0: trades,BANKNIFTY_F_0: relations,NIFTY_F_0: books,NIFTY_F_0: trends,NIFTY_F_0: trades,NIFTY_F_0: relations ]
```

I need the following output:

```
index: 
- BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: [books, trends, trades, relations]
- BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: [books, trends, trades, negrelations]
- BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: [books, trends, trades, relations, options_banknifty_weekly]
- BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: [books, trends, trades, negrelations]
- BANKNIFTY_F_0: [books, trends, trades, relations]
- NIFTY_F_0: [books, trends, trades, relations]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format the input mapping and expected output. It is quite unreadable. Use the `Code Sample` option in the text editor.

Comment: Thanks..I have modified it..Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a single item mapping, with as value a list of single item mappings. 
Your output is a a list of single item mappings. That list is 
 ordered in the same way the keys of the original mappings appear. This indicates that gathering that information should be done using a list or `OrderedDict`

The corresponding values of those mappings is a list of original values for the keys of those mappings, also in the order they appear, but which at least partly repeat in the original, not in the target. Since the order needs preserving, a `set` (which would automatically filter doubles), cannot be used. Instead a list could be used, which requires checking of an item already being in the list. However in the following I use another `OrderedDict`, abused as "`OrderedSet`" by not looking at the values.

The input is assumed to be in the file `input.yaml`:

```
import sys
import pathlib
from collections import OrderedDict
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_file = pathlib.Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None 
data = yaml.load(yaml_file)
indexed = OrderedDict()
for elem in data['index']:
    for k in elem:  # just one each
        single_item_map = indexed.setdefault(k, OrderedDict())
        single_item_map[elem[k]] = None  # arbitrary value, unused
l = []
for elem in indexed:
    l.append({elem: [k for k in indexed[elem]]})
data['index'] = l
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
index:
- BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_09_W: [books, trends, trades, relations]
- BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_09_W: [books, trends, trades, negrelations]
- BANKNIFTY_O_C_0_10_W: [books, trends, trades, relations, options_banknifty_weekly]
- BANKNIFTY_O_P_0_10_W: [books, trends, trades, negrelations]
- BANKNIFTY_F_0: [books, trends, trades, relations]
- NIFTY_F_0: [books, trends, trades, relations]
```

The `yaml.default_flow_style=None` is necessary as by default an instance  `YAML()` will use block style, whereas your output has flow style on the leaf-nodes. More fine tuned control is possible in `ruamel.yaml` by not making "normal" dicts and lists but subclassing the objects internally used for keeping round-trip information. In your case this is not necessary as you want one of the three modes controlled by `.default_flow_style` (`False`: all-block-style, `True`: all-flow-style, `None`: block-style-with-leafs-in-flow-style)

Comment: If does of course help to print `indexed` after it has been created, to see what kind of data structure is built up, that then gets transformed into `l`

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot, Anthon

Comment: @VenugopalBukkala If this solves your problem, please consider marking it accepted. That way other people can directly see what answer solved your question, in case they have a similar problem. That is far more likely than that they read all the way down to the comments.